# Determining what method is best for a comparative sorting algorithm. Divide and Conquer or Hiring Problem for small data collection

Tags: algorithm, sorting, probability, divide-and-conquer

Here is the question I am facing

We have 25 unique materials belonging to a class, and would like
to identify the top 3 out of these 25 materials in terms of their effectiveness.

Unfortunately, we do not have an experimental method that can be used to quantify the effectiveness of a given
material.

Instead, we can run comparative experiments such that each experiment provides a
ranking of 5 materials in terms of their effectiveness (from most effective to least effective).

Running
these experiments is rather expensive, so we would like to minimize the number of experiments she
runs.

**Can you design a strategy that will identify the 3 most effective materials among
25 materials by performing the minimum number of experiments? What is the minimum number
of experiments needed to conclusively determine the 3 most effective materials?**

You do not need
to write pseudo-code; a verbal explanation, possibly supported by graphics, will suffice.

I am confused as to what type of probabilistic analysis I should use to approach this problem. I believe a the hiring problem or divide and conquer would be best for this. Is that correct?

I'm interested in how a professional would approach this type of problem.

Comment: Are these values 25/5/3 the only ones you are interested in? Then it seems easy to show that the top 3 can be selected in 7 experiments

Comment: How does *probability* get into the picture? (I can see *partial* ordering.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach for 7 experiments.

Do 5 groups of 5.  That requires 5 experiments.

Compare the top of each group.  We now have an ordering like this where each row and column is descending.

```
1a 2a 3a 4a 5a
1b 2b 3b 4b 5b
1c 2c 3c 4c 5c
1d 2d 3d 4d 5d
1e 2e 3e 4e 5e
```

The best element is `1a`.  Compare `1b 1c 2a 2b 3a` and you will find the next two best elements.

I don't have a proof that you can't do it with 6.  But I'm sure that that is true.

Comment: `Do 5 groups of 5`, arranging each in a column effectiveness decreasing top-to bottom? `Compare the top of each group.` arrange columns effectiveness of their most efficient (*i*a) element decreasing left-to right? (Didn't I see this Q&A here before? On the order of five years ago?)

Comment: @greybeard Probably.  The question has a familiar flavor to it.  In fact googling around it looks like a variation of https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/25-horses-5-race-tracks-How-many-races-you-have-to-run-to-select-top-5-horses-QTN_136645.htm.

Comment: But the underlying principle is simple.  Always do the experiment that gives you the most information about your answer.  That applies to a wide variety of related problems.